# Aspose Cells. Get rows by group

Tags: aspose, aspose-cells

How can I read rows by group using Aspose?
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mepIl.png)

Answer (score 0):

See the following sample code using Aspose.Cells for your reference:

e.g.

**Sample code:**

```
//Loading the file
Workbook book = new Workbook("e:\\test2\\Bk_readgrouped.xlsx");
//Get the first worksheet in the workbook 
Worksheet sheet = book.Worksheets[0];
    
            int maxRow = sheet.Cells.MaxDataRow;
            int maxCol = sheet.Cells.MaxDataColumn;

            int chk = 0;
            bool pname = false;

            Console.WriteLine("Retrieving each group's data");

            for (int i = 0; i <= maxRow; i++)
            {

                int rowOutlineLevel = sheet.Cells.GetGroupedRowOutlineLevel(i);
                if (rowOutlineLevel > 0)
                {

                    pname = true;
                    if (pname== true & chk != rowOutlineLevel)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\n");
                        Console.WriteLine("Group:" + rowOutlineLevel);
                        pname = false;
                        chk = rowOutlineLevel;
                    }
                    for (int j = 0; j <= maxCol; j++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(sheet.Cells[i, j].StringValue + "\t");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
               
            }
```

Hope, this helps a bit.

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Thx, but this is not I need. I want to get "group", i.e. rows 1-3 belongs to group "1". Is it possible?

Comment: I have enhanced the sample code (above), so you may check it now. Hope, this helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
public virtual void ProcessExcelSheetTree (Worksheet Excelsheet, int current_level)
    {
        int current_row = 1;
        int maxRow = Excelsheet.Cells.MaxDataRow;
        int firstGroupIndex = 0;

        while(Excelsheet.Cells[current_row, 0].StringValue != "")
        {
            var currentRow = Excelsheet.Cells.Rows[current_row];
            if(currentRow.GroupLevel == current_level)
            {
                string targetName = Excelsheet.Cells[current_row, 0].StringValue;
                Console.WriteLine(targetName);

                firstGroupIndex = currentRow.Index;
                for (int i = firstGroupIndex + 1; i <= maxRow; i++)
                {
                    if(Excelsheet.Cells.Rows[i].GroupLevel > current_level)
                    {
                        string subTargetName = Excelsheet.Cells[i, 0].StringValue;
                        Console.WriteLine("     - " + subTargetName);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            current_row++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).